# Query data for specific fields in your main data connection (infopath)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have a SharePoint list with about 85 columns in my main data connection on my InfoPath form. Is it possible to only query 9 fields out of the 85 (in a repeating table) so when my form loads it's not loading every single column(field) for all line items(list items).

I have a drop down box which already hides any repeating table item that's does have the same value as the drop down, but it still queries all data since all the fields are a part of the main data connection, any help would be amazing!

Update**

Just as an update, I removed the query on form load and created a button to query the data with the original data connection, it reduced the query time to around 1 minutes and 15ish seconds, which feels like forever, waiting for it while you can't do anything till it done but it did stop the form giving an error/crashing on load.

I feel like it will just get longer and longer for it to query over time. Does anyone have any suggestions that might help the speed at all?

Would creating a blank view with no fields and just the button to query help at all? then have it switch views or is the query tied to views and that wouldn't matter?